# how to create element only after previous is on stage

Tags: actionscript-3

How do i add a new element only after the previous one has passed the **stage.stageWidth / 2**

except by my way (the code below ,where i create a zone that the element will pass only one time)

PS:I dont want to do it like this cause the speed of movement will be different in time (it will slowly go up and down). Like from 3 to 6 by a easing factor of 0.005

so far i have this

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    private var myArray:Array = new Array();

    public function Main()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame)
        var item:Box = new Box();
        item.x = stage.stageWidth - 100
        item.y = 40
        addChild(item)
        myArray.push(item)
    }

    private function everyFrame(ev:Event):void
    {
        var myBox:Box
        for(var i:int = 0; i< myArray.length; i++)
        {
            myBox = myArray[i]
            myBox.x -=3
            if(myBox.x <= stage.stageWidth/2 && myBox.x >= stage.stageWidth/2 - 3)
            {
                trace("new Box")
                var myNewBox:Box = new Box()
                myNewBox.x = stage.stageWidth - 100
                myNewBox.y = 40
                addChild(myNewBox)
                myArray.push(myNewBox)
            }

            if(myBox.x < 0 )
            {
                removeChild(myBox)
                myArray.splice(i, 1)
                trace(myArray.length)
            }               
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already working and do things as you required.
The code looks like document class, but there is one little mistake that prevent it from execution. You forget `package{...}` wrap. 
But you compiler should say you about this, didn't it?

You are right, using range can provide you bunch of problems then objects didn't get in it, or get several times.
To solve this you could not check area but only `myBox.x<= stage.stageWidth/2` condition. After object met this condition, just remove element from array you use for checking and add it to array of objects which you check for leaving stage to delete them.

If you don't want make another array, you could add some property to every new Box.
For example - `passedCenter` and set it to `false`. Then change if statement for

```
if(myBox.x <= stage.stageWidth/2 && !myBox.passedCenter){
    myBox.passedCenter=true;
    //you stuff
}
```

Comment: :D well i know that.But here (in the code that is shown) im doing it by detecting if the **item.X** is in that area -> between **myBox.x <= stage.stageWidth/2 && myBox.x >= stage.stageWidth/2 - 3** and I know that if i ever increase the **myBox.x -=3** it will never detect it.
so i pasted the code so i can show exactly what im doing and how it behaves , but asking if there is another way of doing this, a way where i dont check for that area.

Comment: Oh, i see. Will add some suggestions to my answer now.

Comment: well i did think it would have to do with a Boolean but my attempts failed and i tried and did it with **setInterval**.But now after your comment :D well now even this works.
the only problem now is which way is more efficient(in memory speaking).

Comment: More efficient is the way you checked only objects what have potential to meet you conditions. With this Boolean property you always check all element in array even if you sure that part them is not your guys.
You have _n_ array accesses and _2n_ `if` checks. If it will be 2 arrays, it still be _n_ array accesses but just _n_ if checks.

Comment: hmmm you have a point there.In the end I think I`ll do it your way,
thanks